# How use decimal in a label with IntVar on tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, decimal

```
from tkinter import *
v=Tk()
v.geometry("400x400")
a= IntVar()
a.set(5.494949)


l=Label(textvariable= a)
l.pack()
```

i use this and return a label with 5.494949 and I need 5.49

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might just help :)

```
from tkinter import *
v=Tk()
v.geometry("400x400")
a= IntVar()
# round function simply rounds the var upto given number of decimal places in the function argument
a.set(round(5.494949,2))

l=Label(textvariable= a)
l.pack()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no explicit support for what you want. However, you can use a `StringVar` or just directly set the value of the label:

```
l = Label(text="%.2f" % 5.494949)
...
l.configure(text="%.2f" % 3.14159)
```